# jQuery UI input inside button - how to prevent triggering click event?

Tags: jquery-ui, events

I got inputs inside button. Is it possible to prevent triggering button click event when clicking on input? `preventDefault()` does not work.

```
<button class="btn_size">
<input type="text" name="size_y" style="width:60px;" />
<font style="font-weight:normal;">x</font>
<input type="text" name="size_y" style="width:60px;" />
Set size
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XeYTJ/

The same happens with `stopPropagation()`. It does not stop it:

http://jsfiddle.net/XeYTJ/2/

Few years ago I had similar problem. I wanted to be able to disable single accordion button. I wrote a function that was able to bind event at the top of any other events, and it just checked if clicked button had `.disabled` class. If yes, it simply did `return false;`. That worked. But only until `jQuery 1.8` came up. Something changed in the access to event data, and it does not work anymore.

This question may seem to be easy, so I do aware that I may get alot of `-1` votes. But please, check if You are able to resolve the problem, before voting.

Comment: event.stopPropagation()?

Comment: Still does not work... http://jsfiddle.net/XeYTJ/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work in two steps:

1. Use the same name in the inputs as in the selectors. You have both inputs `name="size_y"`, but you are using selectors `$('input[name="y_size"]')` and `$('input[name="x_size"]')`. See the difference?
2. Add the click-event on the button before the inputs:

   ```
   $('.btn_size').button({icons: { primary: "ui-icon-arrow-4-diag" }}).click(function(){
       console.log('clicked');
   }); 

   $('input[name="size_x"]').click(function(e){
       console.log('x');
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $('input[name="size_y"]').click(function(e){
       console.log('y');
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
   ```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XeYTJ/3/).

And if that doesn't work, you could try changing `<button>` to `<div>` and use `.button()` to style it.

Comment: Oh indeed its size_x and x_size ... that is a grave mistake. I'm glad you noticed it. The question seems to be usless for most people then, but I won't delete it, because You really deserve to get points for noticing it.

Comment: @flashthunder well, not completely useless. It's still not that straightforward with the order in which to bind to the different click-events.

Comment: Yes you may be right, it is even possible that I tried before with good names but wrong order...